# Jquery or Javascript: Autocomplete from JSON for Multiple Form Fields

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, hidden-field

I have a form with input text field of name 'Building_N'; the form also has a couple of hidden fields which need to be populated from an external JSON file. Currently, the file is a text file with data like:

```
[
  {
   "buildingname":"building1",
   "floorplanlayer":"floorurl",
   "roomlayer": "roomurl",

  },
  {
   "buildingname":"building1",
   "floorplanlayer":"floorurl",
   "roomlayer": "roomurl",
 }
]
```

I would like to use either JQUERY or javascript to allow the users to select the 'buildingname' value and if they do select that then populate the hidden fields with the 'floorplanlayer' and 'roomlayer' values.

I haven't found any example which would allow me to do this. The closest I came was using an Onkeyup event to load the JSON data and then match via Regular Expression but that didn't give the users options to select and also selected by the first character match.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this popular autocomplete library: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

It's more robust than the traditional jQuery UI's autocomplete. This is how I would step through the problem using the API provided by the library:

1. Parse the JSON file into a JavaScript object.
2. Build an array of all of the `buildingname` values.
3. In your autocomplete options, set the `lookup` attribute to your built array.
4. Set the `onSelect` attribute to a callback function that finds the object related to the `buildingname` they selected and set your hidden fields here.

This should make what you are trying to accomplish much easier than tackling autocompletion yourself.

Comment: Thank you. Will take a look. But this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828006/jquery-search-json-and-populate-form-fields?rq=1 should have worked for me but is not.

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: Never mind; per http://www.jensbits.com/2011/08/24/using-jquery-autocomplete-when-remote-source-json-does-not-contain-label-or-value-fields/ jQuery expects a 'label' and I was not using that. So, per the above stackflow.com link my autocomplete is starting to work except it is overlapped by other form input fields--z order problem.

Comment: I fixed the z index; will post my code to show almost working except it is returning all values

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got this to work; note, the autocomplete returns all values because, so far, I am unable to find a way to get the JSON data to match only the starting word. But I guess that will be for another Question:

```
        $("#Building_N").autocomplete({
                 open: function(){
                 setTimeout(function () {
                       $('.ui-autocomplete').css('z-index', 99999999999999);
                 }, 0);
                },
                source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "_buildingdata.txt",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {term: request.term},
                    success: function(data) {
                                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.buildingname,
                                    value: item.buildingname,
                                    hidroom: item.roomlayer,
                                    hidfloor: item.floorplanlayer

                                    };
                            }));//response
                        }//success
                    });//ajax
                },//source
                minLength: 3,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    console.dir(ui);
                    $('#Building_N').val(ui.item.buildingname);
                    $('#hid_roomdata_layer').val(ui.item.hidroom);
                    $('#hid_floorplan_layer').val(ui.item.hidfloor);
                }
         });
```